# How do I include backtick ( ` ) characters inside of an inline code block on this site?

Tags: support, markdown

**How do you write a backtick character inside of an inline code block?**

Given the following SQL which requires backtick characters:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `my-table` LIMIT 1";
```

When I try to write it in inline form via backtick characters it gets corrupted like so:

`$sql="SELECT * FROM`my-table`LIMIT 1";`

**I have tried** using `<code>...</code>` but as soon as it sees two backtick characters, the code gets corrupted because the backticks disappear like so:

`$sql="SELECT * FROM my-table LIMIT 1";`

**I've also tried** using a combination of `<code>` and backticks such as:

```
<code>$sql="SELECT * FROM  </code><code>`</code><code>my-table</code><code>`</code><code> LIMIT 1";</code>
```

But it doesn't work because the two backticks have priority over the `<code>` and corrupt it like so:

`$sql="SELECT * FROM`  `</code><code>my-table</code><code>` `LIMIT 1";`

**The only workaround I've found** is to use the `&#96;` entity but it doesn't work inside of backticks so I'm stuck using:

```
`$sql="SELECT * FROM `&#96;`my-table`&#96;` LIMIT 1";`
```

Which results in the ugly: `$sql="SELECT * FROM```my-table```LIMIT 1";`

**What do you guys on here usually do when you need a backtick inside of an inline code snippet?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As shown in [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) page, under *Code Spans* section:

> If your code itself contains backticks, you may have to use multiple
>   backticks as delimiters:
>
> ```
> The name ``Tuple`2`` is a valid .NET type name.
> ```

Out put of this is: The name `` Tuple`2 `` is a valid .NET type name.

So in your case you use `` at the start and end of your statement. So it will look like:

`` $sql="SELECT * FROM `my-table` LIMIT 1"; ``

Comment: Thanks! That's so much easier!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

```
<code>$sql="SELECT * FROM &#96;my-table&#96; LIMIT 1";</code>
```

Results in: `` $sql="SELECT * FROM `my-table` LIMIT 1"; ``

Comment: This is ugly but works in cases the other answers don't work in.